# I have started to receive a 402 error when accessing my CoreOS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coreos

I have started to receive a 402 error when accessing my CoreOS cluster. It has been working fine up until a day ago. Anybody has any ideas why I'm receiving this error? I am using the stable channel on EC2.

`$ fleetctl list-machines
E0929 09:43:14.823081 00979 fleetctl.go:151] error attempting to check latest fleet version in Registry: 402: Standby Internal Error () [0]
Error retrieving list of active machines: 402: Standby Internal Error () [0]`

Answer (score 0):

In this case `etcd` does not currently have quorum.  The "Standby Internal Error" signifies that the node is attempting to act as a standby but is failing to redirect you to the active node.  Repairing the etcd issue will fix the problem.  Check on the status of etcd by running:

`journalctl -u etcd.service` on each of the nodes should give you the information that you need to repair etcd in this case.